# Two Counts for the for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Can you have two counts with for loop?

Example:

```
for( var count1 = 0, count2 = 0; count1 < 5; count1++, count2++ ) { }
```

If not, what would be a good way to handle two separate counts other than using two loops?

Comment: When you have multiple people giving you the same answer, it's customary to accept the oldest of them. (This is for *future* reference, please don't change it now.)

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder In my defence, I accepted Alex's answer because it answered more than just my question. Both your answer and Jacob acknowledged that it's possible to have two counts, but Alex's  answer tells me I can have MORE than just two counts.

Comment: Gotcha. Mind you, it's too bad `user177883` didn't actually *answer* -- he got there first. :-)

Comment: Slightly OT, but since you clearly have a background in other languages in the same syntactic family: `var` works differently than similar declarations in C, C++, Java, etc. `var` is a function-wide declaration, regardless of where it occurs. So putting `var` anywhere but at the very top can be a bit misleading (although most people do). In particular, the `count1` and `count2` vars in your loop are *not* scoped to the loop, those variables are declared from the very beginning of the function they're in. Just something to watch out for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you can have multiple initializations in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop syntax is completely valid. No problem at all. :)

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you can have multiple counter variables in a for loop. Do you intend the counter variables (count1 and count2) to increment at the same time after each iteration? If so, this is what I'd do:

```
var count2 = 0;
for (var count1 = 0; count1 < 5; count1++)
{
  // Do stuff
  count2++;
}
```

Edit: Nevermind. It's legal. My Javascript's rusty and I've never used multiple control variables in a for loop.